# Looking for fantasy book about girl with hidden powers

Tags: story-identification, magic, love

I think I read the book on Wattpad once, but can't remember the title. It is about a magical world with a strong social hierarchy: the ones with magic at the top, the ones without at the bottom. The story follows a poor girl who thinks she has no magic and has worked all her life. During a gathering where she serves food, she gets assaulted. She reacts with powerful magic. Then she is sent to a school/academy where they teach you to how to control it. She falls in love with a boy who is rumored to have the most powerful magic. During her training, a few attacks happen. The girl discovers that she has very strong powers, and she befriends a wolf.